# Get Negative Position in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Why sometimes negative number Returns the position in RecyclerView ?

for get position :

```
holder.getAdapterPosition()
```

Comment: can you provide a more bit of explanation to your question?

Comment: When `RecyclerView` is in between rendering it return -1 for position . You should Always Check `if(getAdapterPosition()!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()):

> Note that if you've called `notifyDataSetChanged()`, until the next layout pass, the return value of this method will be `NO_POSITION`.
>
> Returns
>   The adapter position of the item if it still exists in the adapter. `NO_POSITION` if item has been removed from the adapter, `notifyDataSetChanged()` has been called after the last layout pass or the `ViewHolder` has already been recycled.

[`NO_POSITION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#NO_POSITION) value is -1.